# How to ovveride java method in Kotlin class

Tags: java, kotlin

I have abstract java class. Also I have kotlin class which extends abstract java class. Why the overrides java methods doesn't calls in kotlin class? For example:

```
public abstract class A {
    public void myMethod() {
   Log.d("test", "test");
    }
}


open class B:A(){
   override fun myMethod {
        super.myMethod()    // doesn't called
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post complete code that we can run to reproduce the problem. For all we know, you're construction the object wrong or not calling myMethod on B.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you just doesn't call `myMethod` from class `B`.

```java
public abstract class A {
    public void myMethod() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

```kotlin
open class B : A() {
    override fun myMethod() {
        super.myMethod()
    }
}

fun main() {
    B().myMethod()
}
```

Code above will print `test` in the console.

Comment: Yes, I call this method from class B.